# How to make program access all files in the file system?

Tags: java, windows, file-permissions

right now, i am writing a program(using java) which want to visit(access) all the files(files/directories) in the file system in windows. I would like to know how can I make my program able to access all the files without a permission deny? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't. This is up to the administrator to determine which user has access to what.

Comment: How I can make my program has access privilege to all files? I am actually writing a program using java's NIO.watchservice, and I want to register all files in my filesystem, but got access denied for some files in C drive

Comment: A `WatchService` on _all files_? That will use quite a lot of OS resources.

Comment: Yeah, but just want to monitor some format of files like .txt or .pfd, but these can be anywhere in the file system, that's why i need monitor the whole filesystem

Comment: If these can be anywhere in the filesystem, you have another problem imho. I don't know what your requirements are (you don't tell) but the locations in which files are expected should be well defined

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to redefine the file locations. I found a class called java.io.FilePermission. They have a example: FilePermission p = new FilePermission("<<ALL FILES>>", "read"); with the comment: Note that "<<ALL FILES>>" is a special string denoting all files in the system. I add this line to my program but it seems not working.

Comment: This has nothing to do; this `FilePermission` class is made to be used by a `SecurityManager`, and this is only enforced by the JVM. The problem you have is at the OS level.

Comment: So for this problem, the only way to solve this problem is redefine the file locations?

Comment: That is the most sensible solution anyway, so yes, I highly recommend you do that -- ensure you define a location where you know your users will be able to write to and you read from

Comment: Impossible from Java.  Win32 code allows you to use restore privilege to bypass permissions, but even then you may get denied access to files that another process has open.

Comment: if don't consider files that open by other process, how to get permission to access files programmactically?

Answer (score 1):

Run the program from a user with access privileges to the files of interest

Comment: Mhhhm, not absolutely true. Some files are inaccessible, even for administrator.